# Has this "lyrics with song" style of scene ever been done?

Tags: first-appearance, baby-driver

In the movie [Baby Driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_Driver), in the Coffee Run scene, some of the lyrics of the song are plastered in graffiti on the walls while the main character walks to the coffee shop.

**Has this ever done before or was Edgar Wright the one who created it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's done.

In Telugu movie *Sye* (2004), there is a song *Urura Urura*. The main characters literally sing what is shown on wall posters, cutouts, and hoardings. (I am a Telugu speaking person.)

The postures, hoardings are in Telugu and he reads the same. For English for crosschecking, see the video from 1:13 to 1:24.